# Google maps API is not returning the right locality

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have the following latitude and longitude:
https://www.google.com/maps/place/41.431152,2.218045
If you navigate to this url, you'll see that you are in a city called "Sant Adria de Besos" in Spain.

Now, when I'm using the same coordinate in the Get Location API of Google Maps (Reverse geolocalization), I'm getting the correct address (including for the postal code) except for the locality which becomes "Santa Coloma de Gramenet" (as you can see in the screenshot below) which is another city close to Sant Adria de Besos.

[Screenshot from Make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyfJW.png)

I've tried taking various latitude/longitude parameters in Sant Adria de Besos but I still get the same issue.

I wondering what is the issue. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As this question is more about data issue within the Google Maps, it would be best for you to file a support case: https://developers.google.com/maps/support or send feedback to the Google Maps App itself by following these instructions: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094045

Answer (score -1):

I've just tried this with the Geocoding API as part of the Google Maps Platform API and it does indeed return an address which says Santa Coloma de Gramenet which should be Sant Adria de besos, take a look at the links below:

https://maps.app.goo.gl/coHdWVEcg2qR6nQr6 - Santa Coloma de Gramenet
https://maps.app.goo.gl/ovckfTH6GFj16FRWA - Sant Adria de besos

The lat/lng of 41.431152,2.218045 is clearly within Sant Adria de Besos.

Contact Google Maps Platform Support about this so they can check it and, if possible, fix it for you.

https://developers.google.com/maps/support